# Shuffling a JSON array in Java

Tags: java, array, json, shuffle

Since I did not get a satisfactory answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531130/an-efficient-way-to-shuffle-a-json-array-in-java) (and I really needed to get it going on this weekend), I decided to implement my own Fisher–Yates shuffle, porting the code I found in other SO posts. I know my programming technique is far from optimal, so I decided to post this here.

What do you think? Can it be improved?

```
public static JSONArray shuffleJsonArray (JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
    // Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = array.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
          int j = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
          // Simple swap
          Object object = array.get(j);
          array.put(j, array.get(i));
          array.put(i, object);
        }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs in \$O(n)\$ time so I'm not sure there's a way to improve this.  It looks like you've implemented the algorithm pretty well, according the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

You might consider not using `Object` if you can use the type that's stored in the array instead.

I also thought I read somewhere that it should be safe to loop to \$n/2\$ instead of \$n\$ (because you're swapping with elements from \$1 \cdots n\$ so in theory, you shouldn't need to swap every element), but I don't have hard proof of that, so you take your chances ;)

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I based it on that wikipedia page and a couple of posts in SO. I will keep in mind the n/2 loops to change it if needed. Lastly, I wrote it using `JSONObject` instead of `Object` but then I changed it to make it more reusable. What would be the advantage of using `JSONObject` instead?

Comment: @Aleadam: I don't know the JSONArray datatype well, I guess I was trying to suggest to use Java generics so you don't have to use `Object`, but I don't know if you can do that with JSONArray.

Comment: I also think that there is no faster way for shuffling an array. Every try in doing it faster (O(log n) or O(sqrt n)) would result in a poorly shuffled array.